# Can you use internet without Dns

Tags: networking, dns, internet

Forgive me if I lack understanding of the concept of DNS but from what I can gather it is just the addressing of an IP to a more readable string of characters. 
I've seen the analogy that it is similar to a phone book in that you could memorize the numbers but it is much easier to have the phone book.

With that being said if say, a dns server crashed(aka lose my phone book), could I then still access the site I wish using it's raw IP address(a memorized phone number)?

To clarify I'm not asking if the internet as a whole could/would work without dns I am referring to an event where my ISP's dns is down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: Yes and no.

It depends on the configuration of the server. For example, a shared webhosting will have many domains pointed to the same IP address. The server translates which domain is being used and redirects traffic to the right site. If you access the site by IP address on a shared webhosting server, the server does not know where it needs to direct your traffic to, and as such you will get their own website, or a blank site or even worse a "this website is not configured yet - default" kind of website.

However, if there is only one website located and the server accepts traffic on port 80, then yes, you can access the website purely by ip address.

In any case, this is not something you will want.

Instead, you will want to change your DNS server on your client computer. Usually 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are used (they're google's DNS servers). If you setup this DNS server, you can still do DNS translations and thus access websites by their domain name, and it will work.

Comment: You beat me by a minute. You should also mention the fact that many websites might have more than 1 IP address. DNS will try to connect to the best available. This can be for load balancing or redundancy. Or to serve web pages based on the user location

Comment: @D.A Although its true that a website can have more than one IP address for load balancing, it doesn't technically matter if you remember one of the two ip addresses to access the site that way. It is interesting to know, but does not change the outcome of this particular question.

Comment: It matters on the understanding of the concept of DNS that the OP mentions in the first sentence. It is not just addressing the IP, it can do a lot more. But I get what you say

Answer (score 0):

While technically you can open up a web site in the `http://<ip>` format, that doesn't mean that you'll necessarily see the same content as if you opened the `http://<fqdn>` format.

This mainly happens because of the configuration of the web servers, where sites are usually referenced by the `FQDN` instead of the IP address.

Most of these web sites have a "default" site which will act as a fallback in case of no other site matches the `FQDN`.

Keep in mind that there are sites that have thousands of domains on the same server and content will appear depending on the `FQDN` you open.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. If DNS server crashes, you can use IP to address server directly, without a need to resolve the name. For that reason many prefer to use Google DNS aka 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, those are mostly bulletproof.
But keep in mind that setting DNS does not always help, since some sleazy ISP's like to force their own DNS servers on users to spam advertisements.
Since this is kind of offtopic, if you are interested you should read a good article about this
https://hackercodex.com/guide/how-to-stop-isp-dns-server-hijacking/

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

In theory, you can indeed use the address instead of the name in many network related applications, but often this won't work for web pages, because the server you are talking to is a "virtual" server: there are actually several servers at that same address, and the "real" server looks at the server name in the URL to determine to which server your request should be forwarded(*).

This case is easily handled by making you own PC convert names to addressees. There is a "hosts" file (`/etc/hosts/` on linux, `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in Windows) that is looked up before your PC goes to the DNS server, so you can put names<->addresses there and used the as if they were obtained by a regular DNS. Editing this file may make security software raise alarms because malware can also alter this file to reroute you to unwanted sites.

However, there are cases where even this won't work, because the address changes dynamically (load balancing), or your web server is behind a "content delivery network" (static things are served from a server close to you, only the "personalized" part is obtained from the real server). So you have to use a proper DNS anyway. But nothing forces you (except local law) to use your ISP's name servers, you can configure your PC to use specific name servers (somewhere in your network settings), the most used for this being Google's 8.8.8.8 and OpenDNS 208.67.220.220 and 208.67.220.222.

(*) actually the server name in the HTTP headers... but your browser use the one in the URL for this.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. If you know the website's IP adddress then you can connect directly  using http://`IP adddress`.

Comment: -1 because this is simply not true.

Comment: @LPChip [http://108.177.119.104](http://108.177.119.104)

Comment: See my answer why it is not true. It can work in case of a dedicated server, but it will fail in case of a shared webhosting server.

Comment: @LPChip You're right.